# How can I enable Gradle file system watching persistently?

Tags: gradle

Gradle has this new feature that listen to file system events instead of touching the filesystem to detect changes to local files.

It can be enabled on the command line with `--watch-fs`. How can it be enabled persistently in a file that I would check in source control?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of today, with Gradle 6.5 you can enable the experimental feature by putting the following in `gradle.properties` in the project root, or in your `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` file:

```
org.gradle.unsafe.watch-fs=true
```

The feature will eventually be enabled by default, and the property name will change (losing the `unsafe` part).

Answer (score 3):

Blog post from May 2020 gives the property as this:

`org.gradle.vfs.watch=true`

https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-file-system-watching

and it's confirmed on the Build Properties list here (for Gradle 7.0 and up):

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties

[image: explainer of the url shared]